# How can I work out statistically if there is a significant difference between 3 numbers?

Tags: statistical-significance, spss, differences

I have a list of participants who all gave answers to three variables.
I created scores for each answer i.e: a smiley face = 5 to a sad face = 1
I then added up these scores for each participant, for each variables. For example for one participant, I have scores of 47, 40 and 39 for each of the variables. Obviously 47 looks bigger than the others, but how can I statistically assess that there is a significant difference between these numbers (or not) and where the difference lies? I would like to do this one participant at a time, for each of my participants (all of whom have different scores).

I've considered one way anova, friedman etc but none seem to be right because of the small sample size n=1

Comment: What exactly are you trying to find? You can either compare groups of participants (assuming they are samples of a larger population) or whether their evaluations of each variable are different.

Comment: I want to see if participants are more of one variable than another if that make sense. So if 47 is variable 1, 40 is variable 2 and 39 is variable 3 it would seem as  though the participant is more heavily weighted on variable 1 but it could be that the differences aren't significant and that in fact they weight equally on all 3 variables (or 2 in other cases) so in answer to your question I assume whether their evaluations of each variable are different.